# What is the alternative to IOptionsSnapshot in .NET 7?

Tags: asp.net-core

IOptionsSnapshot cannot be used in .NET 7

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

private readonly SiteSettings _siteSetting;
public JwtService(IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSettings> settings)
{
    _siteSetting = settings.Value;
}
```

How to get app setting information in .NET 7?

I couldn't use IOptionsSnapshot and apparently it doesn't exist anymore in .NET 7.

Comment: [It exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Why do you claim it doesn't? Did you forget a `using` directive perhaps?

Comment: The edit contradicts the question itself. Again, why do you claim that `IOptionsSnapshot` doesn't exist? Did you get a compilation error? A runtime error? If what you claimed was true .NET 7 would never be released. *All* tutorials, and projects would be broken